# htc wildfire s after update to 2.3.5 - cannot install any app

Tags: updates, bugs, htc-wildfire-s

After updating my wildfire s phone to android version 2.3.5 I cannot install any application or update existing ones. Downloading icon appears for 1 sec and instantly disappears - for some reason apps wont download.

Friend of mine has very same problem with his wildfire s, so it looks like not an accident with my phone but real reproducable issue.

Does anyone managed to fix it without factory data reset?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, tried cleaning cache and data with no result.

So I went in settings > applications > manage apps > all, picked the download manager and "uninstalled the updates". It told me the app would reset to factory settings, and when I started the phone again, it was running marketplace 3.4.4 and I managed to update and install apps normally after that.

Disclaimer: I only tried that because I planed to do a factory reset if I broke everything. I don't guarantee the results.

Comment: Thanks, Meri. Your solution works! It's a pity new Download Manager is so buggy, because I also have issues with old one - very ofter it downloads application but they won't install, have to redownload several times to get app installed.

Comment: Glad I could help. As for the apps not installing, I wish I knew how to fix that, it's a problem I encountered too.